# I want to add google mobile ad dependency to my build.gradle file. But it is showing a red marked underline which occurs run time crash to my app

Tags: android, dependencies, admob, google-mobile-ads

I want to show ad in my app using Admob. But when I add google mobile ad dependency to my build.gradle file and sync project, it is showing red underline. It is showing "All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification" How to solve it? I add google() to my build.gradle(project) file and tried to add updated version of dependency.

build.gradle file, project level gradle file, manifest file:

````
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nabil.drawerlayout"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
}




```



project level gradle:


```

    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```





manifest file:



```

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nabil.drawerlayout">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AfterSearchActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".AfterallBusFragmentActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FaqActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".AboutAppActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_app_id"/>

    </application>

</manifest>

```
````

Comment: post the project level gradle file

Comment: did it. @SantanuSur

Comment: What is your gradle in gradle-wrapper.properties? it must be more than 4.1 as doc say https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: It's 4.1 @VadimEksler

Comment: did you tried Build>Clean project?

Comment: No @VadimEksler